# String regex with groups

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to use the `String.replaceAll` method for replacing a String like `<br>` with `<br/>`. Because `<br>` can be something more complicated like `<br style="">`, I need the same regex to work on both cases.

I tried something like:

```
String s = "<something><br><br style=\"\"></something>";
s = s.replaceAll("<br(.*)>", "<br$1/>");
```

but it doesn't seem like I am very successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the regex ungreedy:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<br(.*?)>", "<br$1/>");
```

or:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<br([^>]*)>", "<br$1/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this expression:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<br(.*?)>", "<br$1/>");
```